# 万端　ｖｓ　完了 in this context

Tags: expressions

I was listening to a song the other day when I saw this. The lyrics in question:

> [帰宅]{きたく}[完了]{かんりょう}。ダウンロード[完了]{かんりょう}。[配信]{はいしん}スタート。[準備]{じゅんび}[万端]{ばんたん}。

According to Jisho 万端 means

> all； everything

To me, it makes it hard to understand why they say 準備万端 when faced with this definition. If they were to use 完了 instead would it mean the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

準備万端 is a kind of set phrase which uses four kanji characters in a compound. They are called [yojijukugo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yojijukugo) (四字熟語). They are commonly used as idiomatic phrases in Japanese. You could replace it with 準備完了 but it wouldn't have quite the same impact, even though the meaning isn't that different.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what デジタル大辞泉 says about this:

> #### [ばん‐たん【万端】](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%87%E7%AB%AF/)
>
> １ ある事についてのあらゆる事柄・方法。「千緒 (せんしょ) 万端」「準備万端整う」
>
> ２ 俗に、すべてが整っていること。万全。「準備は万端だ」
>
> [補説] 2は「万端整えてある」からの誤解。

And 明鏡国語辞典 第二版 says:

> #### ばん‐たん【万端】
>
> 名ある物事についてのすべての事柄。また、あらゆる手段・方法。「準備━整う」「諸事━の世話をする」「家事（の）━を取り仕切る」
>
> 注意: 手ぬかりがない意の「万全」と混同するのは誤り。「× 警備に万端を期す（○ 万全を期す）」

So the "correct" meaning of 万端 is "all/everything (about something)", but in reality, 万端 often also means "completely done/ready" today. Some dictionaries still don't mention this usage at all, and some explicitly says it's wrong. However some started to accept this usage of 万全 as a slangy derivative meaning.

Please see this article from 毎日新聞's proofreading department, too: [準備は「万全だ」？「万端だ」？](https://mainichi-kotoba.jp/enq-014)